# get all fields of object

Tags: object, field, racket

Is it possible in racket to get all fields of an object at the same time?

I would like basically to convert an object to a hash table with field names as keys and field values as values.

I found a function (field-names obj), but then I don't know how to use the returned field names to get the values from the obj. The function `get-field` can be used to get the value of a field, but I dont know how to use it with a value:

```
> (define x% (class object% (init-field x y) (super-new)))
> (define obj (make-object x% 1 2))
> (get-field x obj)
1
> (field-names obj)
'(y x)
> (define field-name (second (field-names obj)))
> field-name
'x
> (get-field field-name obj)
get-field: given object does not have the requested field
  field name: field-name
  object: (object:x% ...)
  errortrace...:
  context...:
    /usr/lib/racket/collects/racket/private/class-internal.rkt:4906:0: obj-error29
    /usr/lib/racket/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:87:7
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's some code to get you started

```
#lang racket

> (define x% (class object% (inspect #f) (init-field x y) (super-new)))
> (define obj (make-object x% 1 2))
> (let-values (((name field-cnt field-name-list field-accessor field-mutator super-class skipped) 
               (class-info x%)))
    (for/hash ((name field-name-list)
               (idx field-cnt))
      (values name (field-accessor obj idx))))
'#hash((x . -1) (y . 0))
```

You may want to change the inspector from #f to something less vulnerable, but open enough for your needs.  Read up on class-info and inspectors in general.

Comment: That thing on inspectors is tricky at best. There is no real documentation and/or use cases/patterns for good practices.